# Set NSTask working directory

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, foundation

How do I set the working directory of an `NSTask`. The obvious choice is `currentDirectoryPath`, but [it is deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstask/1413110-currentdirectorypath?preferredLanguage=occ).

The program I am running needs to be run in a specific directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The **obvious** choice* is `currentDirectoryURL`.

Apple is going to replace all `(NS)String` path related API with `(NS)URL` related API.

- `currentDirectoryPath` is deprecated in 10.13 but still operational.
- `currentDirectoryURL` is introduced in 10.13.

The same occurs to `launchPath` which will become `executableURL`

Comment: Ah this should have been obvious but they buried it at the [bottom of the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstask?language=objc).

Comment: It's mentioned in one of the WWDC videos that strings will be replaced with URLs bit by bit.